# Is "tantamount" only for negative things?

Tags: meaning

Is it possible to say "A is tantamount to B" where B is not a negative thing?

Can "is tantamount to" be used with neutral or positive things, as a perfect synonym of "is equivalent to"? Or is it incorrect / awkward?

Comment: Have you looked in any dictionaries? Please include details of your research, and what you don't understand about what you found.

Comment: Some dictionary definitions say that "tantamount" is for negative things, while others do not. Most example sentences that I found refer to negative things, but a small number of them also refer to neutral/positive things.

Comment: Dictionaries do not always agree, and Cambridge is a sufficiently reputable reference source to support a positive or neutral usage.

Answer (score 1):

Cambridge Dictionary says that 'tantamount' means:

> *being **almost** the same* **OR** *having the same effect* as something, **usually** something bad.

This conveys the following information:

Tantamount can mean nearly the same as something (not just exactly the same)

Tantamount can mean 'having the same effect' as something.

Tantamount is most often used negatively, but does not have to be always used negatively.

[Tantamount (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tantamount)

Merriam-Webster gives this meaning:

> equivalent in value, significance, or effect

That dictionary gives this **positive or neutral** example:

> a relationship tantamount to marriage

Collins Dictionary gives this meaning, which is unequivocally negative:

> If you say that one thing is tantamount to a second, more serious
> thing, you are emphasizing how bad, unacceptable, or unfortunate the
> first thing is by comparing it to the second.

Longman gives this positive example

> For campaign strategists, this was tantamount to spinning straw into
> gold.

Grammarist gives a neutral example:

> we could say that a pitcher of beer is tantamount to a six-pack.

Psychology Today (neutral/positive):

> While optimism is not tantamount to happiness, optimists and the very
> happy both have strong social networks.

**Summary: You can use 'tantamount' positively, neutrally, or negatively (there is sufficient support), but be prepared to defend a positive or neutral usage if it is criticised by people who have only looked in one dictionary, or who are convinced of it only having a negative implication**

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am not a linguist so I will not have to defend the positive or neutral usage by mentioning dictionary definitions to other linguists or students. What worries me is whether my native readers will find the usage awkward or wrong.

Comment: @goalie - you cannot ensure that none of your readers will be ignorant or opinionated.

Comment: @goalie - I live with my girlfriend, in a house we own together. We have been together for 30 years, and we love each other. That is tantamount to being married, and, believe me, it is a very positive thing.

Comment: @goalie I'm a native speaker, and I find all neutral and positive uses of "tantamount" to be awkward and wrong.

Comment: @gotube - I'll concede they are a little formal in ordinary conversation, but I don't see anything 'wrong' with 'admission to the bar is not tantamount to being engaged in a trade or business of practicing law.' (Journal of Accountancy US, 2004) or 'Not being able to hear your tinnitus, forgetting that you have tinnitus and no longer needing treatment for tinnitus is tantamount to being cured.' (UK ENT surgeon 2002).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I was probably unclear. I'm *not* asserting that it's awkward or wrong. The OP wants to know if some native speakers feel it is awkward or wrong, and I certainly do. I'm now aware that there are several worthy attestations of it used non-negatively, but it still *feels* wrong to me, and that's what the OP was asking about.

Comment: @gotube - isn't 'feels wrong' tantamount to 'opinion based'?

Comment: Who said (or sang) 'How can it be wrong if it feels so right'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I see your point. I think the matter of whether this is opinion-based is opinion-based. For me, I think it's a legit learner's question to ask, "*Will a significant portion of native speakers reading this think this usage is awkward or wrong, or will just about everyone reading this think it is correct and natural?*" To me, that question is verifiable, not opinion-based.